# Mixer module won't initiate

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I've been trying to get into pygame, and I want to play a sound. I try to initiate the mixer module like this:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
```

When I run it, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (moce recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 5 in <module>
        pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory
```

I am running the code on repl.it, and I'm unsure if its repl's issue, as it has caused issues on code that ran perfectly on the default IDLE.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

pygame.mixer won't work on *repl.it* as it doesn't have an audio device associated with it

as you said it works on IDLE. It is because your device has an audio device

Comment: why do you assume that TC run code in repl.it ?

Comment: @r2d2 sorry, what is full form of TC